# Ad banner in side menu may overflow the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising

The ad in the side menu sometimes is the same size of the top banner ad (in that case, 729px x 90px). I managed to reproduce this a few times on the Home page and on the question page.

Browser 1: Opera GX - version LVL2 (core: 76.0.4017.208)
Browser 2: Chrome - version 91.0.4472.124
OS: Windows 10 - version 2004 (OS build 19041.1083)

[image: Ad overflowing on right]

[image: Developer tools]

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome here, but not Firefox.

Comment: Unable to repro. Might be associated with this specific add, I only got adds for Amazon AWS. Did you try reporting the add, using the link right below the add.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce I kept getting square ads. In theory the issue might be inappropriately placed banner ads - and there's enough info to sus it out

Comment: Hm, I'm not being able to reproduce it today. I only get square and [rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x2LG.png) ads. But _loom_ horizontal ad is still shown on top, so I know the ad still exists. Is it possible to know if "it fixed itself"? Or maybe someone landed a fix? I don't know if it's an SO or Google side issue, but every time it happened yesterday, it was with the same ad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This is now fixed. A banner-size ad creative mistakenly had a wrong size override.